# Synchronizing HttpURLConnection and KeyListener:

Tags: java, synchronization, httpurlconnection, keylistener

So, I'm trying to write code for a search JTextField that retrieves results from the web (kinda like Google's fancy search tips). The only problem is... probably my lack of programming experience. More specifically, I have it set up to whenever a user hits a key, it sends out a request with the JTextField input through an HttpURLConnection and retrieves the results then updates. But whenever the HttpURLConnection is running, it freezes the program for a couple seconds while it does its thing, which mainly prohibits entering in more characters into the search field if I didn't mind anything else. I've considered using separate threads, but I'm not sure how I would properly interrupt a thread and have it start over using new data while having everything else wait on it but still accepting new data. I've considered using

```
thread.stop();
```

to help manage the issue, but from what I've read, that seems taboo (am I right?). Anyways, here's pretty much what I'm using:

```
public class SearchField extends JTextField implements KeyListener {
    public SearchField() {
        addkeyListener(this);
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<String results) {
        /*Pass the data off the the GUI*/
    {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        SearchQuery query = new SearchQuery(this.getText());
        updateData(query.getResults());
    }
}


public class SearchQuery {

    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    public SearchQuery(String search) {
        String search_path = "http://www.whatever.com/" + search;
        URL url = new URL(search_path);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76"); 
        in = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        int i;
        while((i = in.read()) != -1) {
            buf.append((char) i);
        }
        String data = buf.toString();

        parse(data);
    }

    public void parse(String data) {
        /*Parse a bunch of JSON, return the results in an array*/
        results.add(data);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getResults() {
        return results;
    }
}
```

I'm just at a loss for how to synchronise recieving continuous input while getting new results for each key stroke and dismissing unfinished connections and their respective data processing when it becomes invalid at the next key stroke.

Comment: You need to perform the search in a different thread if you don't want the Event Dispatch Thread to freeze.

Comment: Should I just dispose of the current thread each time it recieves new input? And how would I get it to wait on the thread to finish getting its results before updating the GUI?

Comment: You could mark old threads as unneeded with a simple boolean flag, so they wouldn't update the GUI if a more recent thread is getting results. Also see the answer provided by tbodt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the download in the same thread that responds to user events. You need to do the download in another thread, perhaps by making `SearchQuery` extend `Thread` and doing the query in the `run` method. When it comes time to update the text field, you can use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to update the text field. Here’s an example:

```
public class SearchQuery extends Thread {
    private SearchField f;
    public SearchQuery(JTextField f) {
        this.f = f;
    }

    public void run() {
        // do the query here
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                f.updateData(results);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then change the line:

```
SearchQuery query = new SearchQuery(this.getText());
```

to this:

```
SearchQuery query = new SearchQuery(this);
```

Comment: Ooh, that might be the answer right there. I'll have to do some research on SwingUtilities.invokeLater and figure out how to use it to update my components. Do you have any good resources on it?